# C++ Passing pointer to function expecting void* works in two different ways, why?

Tags: c++, function, void, void-pointers

Recently I stumbled accross code I melted into this example:

```
void PrintThis (void* input)
{
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    std::cout << (char*)input << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    char question[] = "Why does it work?";
    PrintThis(question);    // output: address + 'Why does it work?' - expected!
    PrintThis(&question);   // output: address + 'Why does it work?' - unexpected
    char* thisIsDiff = "This is different";
    PrintThis(thisIsDiff);    // output: address + 'This is different' - expected
    PrintThis(&thisIsDiff);   // output: address + rubbish - expected
    return 0;
}
```

Please note the line marked with *unexpected*. Why is the output the same as the line above? And why does it not even compile when function paramter is char* instead of void?